# How to convert a string containing object properties into associative array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I hava a string which i get it from a Java SDK call. it is like so:

```
{confirmationReferenceId=126c023b-0031-4fec-9257-c31913355289, error=[], warning=[{code=1105, msg=Some Message, detail=[]}], success=true}
```

How can i convert it to an associative array in php so that i could access its elements like this:

```
$array['confirmationReferenceId'] 
$array['warning'][0]['msg']
```

Thx in advance

Comment: So it is JSON, but without the quotes?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, It seems so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert your string to the valid JSON string, use `str_replace` and `preg_replace` to replace `=` with `:` and add `"` around keys and values respectively. The regex matches non-empty word characters (incl. white-spaces & hyphens). Then just use `json_decode` with true flag.

```
<?php

$input = '{confirmationReferenceId=126c023b-0031-4fec-9257-c31913355289, error=[], warning=[{code=1105, msg=Some Message, detail=[]}], success=true}';

$jsonString = str_replace('=', ':', $input);
$jsonString = preg_replace('/\b(\w[\w\s-]*\w|\w)/', '"$1"', $jsonString);
$array = json_decode($jsonString , true);
print_r($array);

 ?>
```

[DEMO](https://www.tehplayground.com/0UcIdbzXaINnxkH8)

Comment: This will break with a _value_ containing an `=`.